# How to refresh cache of Amazon S3 Storage for static webpage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

I was searching Amazon support forums and found a thread - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=346895&#346895 - with the same, unanswered question...

CMD + SHIFT + DELETE: clearBrowserData (from the beginning of time)

CMD + R: to refresh

#### No effect

http://www.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yoga/Home.html - **WORKS**
http://www.example.com/yoga/Home.html - **DAMNIT**

Any way to force refresh webpage hosted on Amazon S3?

Comment: Did you try another browser?  Or try adding a query parameter to the end of the URL. Browsers cache by URI not file, so if it's a browser cache problem, that's one way to quickly identify it. Also, are you using S3 or is it frontend by CloudFront (or whatever their CDN is called?) I've heard there can be server cache issues with that service.

Comment: Are you getting older page information for http://www.XXX.com/yoga/Home.html - DAMNIT and updated information @ http://www.XXX.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yoga/Home.html - WORKS IS IT ? or you are getting error message ?

Comment: I was getting older version. Now it is fixed, magically...

Comment: Now it is fixed (patience, patience). Next time when similar situation occurs I will try adding some ?query to string URL. I was acutally trying other browser with no effect. BTW: I'm point using S3 via CNAME record.

Comment: The CNAME shouldn't have any effect. It sounds like your cache finally flushed itself. My suggestion is to talk to the person who set the CDN up and see if you can get access to flushing the server/CDN cache when you need to. Set that up now so you're prepared for next time. :)  Good luck!

Comment: My problem is simply with a S3 static web site, that I have updated a page in the bucket, but the updates just won't show anywhere. It's been a week. There is no cloud front or other caching enabled that I am aware of. I've tried different browser and device, just the same old page - does anyone have any advise on what to do here, short of actually renaming the page and updating all links to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it is silly but at least changes have immediate effect :)

[image: Immediate changes]

Comment: Its Okay if it is running. But to delete file and upload again. thats mean it is the problem of Amazon S3, Not of Browner.
Yes it is really silly :)